# How to add next and previous buttons programmatically in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton

Here in image view, how to add next and previous buttons (front and back options) programmatically in iPhone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create a button in uiview programmatically in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779220/how-to-create-a-button-in-uiview-programmatically-in-iphone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding Button in image View?

If so, code as follows

```
    UIButton *nextBut=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    nextBut.frame= CGRectMake(x, y, 120, 100);
    [nextBut setTitle:@"Next" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [nextBut addTarget:self action:@selector(nextbuttonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.imageView addSubview:nextBut];
    [nextBut release];

    UIButton *prevBut=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    prevBut.frame= CGRectMake(x, y, 120, 100);
    [prevBut setTitle:@"Previous" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [prevBut addTarget:self action:@selector(prevbuttonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.imageView addSubview:prevBut];
    [prevBut release];
```

x,y is the position of the button in your view.

Then code for the button actions,

```
-(IBAction)nextbuttonAction
{
//Next Button Action
}

-(IBAction)prevbuttonAction
{
//Previous Button Action
}
```

**EDIT:**

set the pickerView delegate. In the following method code as follows,

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
 imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:row]];
}
```

Comment: post some of your code here so that it will be easy for me to answer.

Comment: check my edited answer and make sure that you set the delegate for pickerView

Answer (score 0):

put all images in a array (let imageArray)and take global variable of integer type for the current image (let curIndex)
increment and decrement the global variable nextbuttonAction and prevbuttonAction respectively

and change the image of imageview control from imageArray from index curIndex ([imageArray objectAtIndex:curIndex])