# how to create a button in uiview programmatically in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit

In my iPhone application, how to add next and previous buttons in uiview programmatically?

Comment: May i know what is the problem with this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778491/how-to-add-next-and-previous-buttons-programmaticaly-in-iphone/4778594#4778594

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add next and previous buttons programmatically in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778491/how-to-add-next-and-previous-buttons-programmatically-in-iphone)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create dynamic buttons using the following code

```
    UIButton *but=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    but.frame= CGRectMake(200, 15, 15, 15);
    [but setTitle:@"Ok" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [but addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:but];
```

Comment: I thought the UI buttonWithType creation method returns an autoreleased UIButton? If that is true that you can't release the UIButton programmatically but wait for garbage collection to do it for you.